# Devoid and Lack

Tags: verbs, differences

I often found it hard to use "devoid" naturally and correctly. And most of the times it seems to me that replacing "devoid" by "lacking" sounds more natural.

> The question is **lacking** meaning
>   The question is **devoid** of meaning

What is the difference for these two sentences? Do they mean the exact same thing?

*Devoid* seems to be a very strong word to me and it seems like it is suggesting that something had happened which removes something from something. And it seems that the same connotation does not apply to *lacking*. Am I correct?

Comment: "lack" is a verb or a noun, but "devoid" is an adjective.

Comment: Have you consulted a dictionary, Alan? If so please include the results of that research in your OP, and then tell us what remains uncertain about the difference between these words.

Comment: This question seems *devoid* of all research. Due to this *lack* of research I expect it will be placed on hold until the question can be improved.

Comment: *This house is devoid of decor/this house lacks decor/this house is lacking in decor.*

Comment: Thank you for the comments. actually I should have made my question clearer. What I am unsure about is something like:

The question is lacking meaning;
The question is devoid of meaning

What is the difference for these two sentences? Do they mean the exact same thing?

Wh
I am not sure how to clearly express myself, sorry

Comment: To make myself clearer.

The question is lacking meaning;
The question is devoid of meaning

What is the difference between these two sentences? Do they mean the exact same thing? devoid seems to be a very strong word to me and it seems like it is suggesting that something had happened which devoid something of something. And it seems that the same connotation does not apply to "lacking"

Am I correct?

Comment: Hi Alan,  I edited your question to reflect the additional information you put into your comments, so that people don't have to read the comments to get a full picture of what you're trying to ask.  Feel free to edit the question further if I didn't get something quite right or if you think of anything else you'd like to add to explain what you're trying to get figured out.

Comment: To be *lacking* means there ***isn't enough*** of something.  To be *devoid* of something means there ***isn't any***

Answer (score 1):

When we say something is devoid of this or that, we mean that it is *completely* lacking this or that. When we speak of a lack of something, we usually do not mean a total absence.

Answer (score -1):

Wrt your two critical expressions:

At Google Books

[**question lacks meaning**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22question%20lacks%20meaning%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl)
About 83 results

[**question is devoid of meaning**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22question%20lacks%20meaning%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22question%20is%20devoid%20of%20meaning%22)
About 54 results

have comparable frequencies and meanings, but the 2nd has more emphasis.

In order to see that, take a look at "devoid" on this page of the best source for separating synonyms:

> [Merriam-Webster's Dictionary of Synonyms: A Dictionary of
>   Discriminated ...](https://books.google.ca/books?id=8N4UReTJYhUC&pg=PA237&dq=merriam%20webster%20synonym%20dictionary%20devoid&hl=en&sa=X&ei=3jQYVbaoKPPIsQTV34HoBg&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=merriam%20webster%20synonym%20dictionary%20devoid&f=false)
>
> shows **entire** want or lack
>
> **stresses** the absence or the nonpossession of a particular quality, character, or tendency